# How to disable zoom in chart control in C#?

Tags: c#, charts, zooming

How can i disable zoom after mouse selection in `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control in a .Net 4.0 WinForms application? Actually I want to use selected area in other case but not for zooming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set:

```
chart.ChartAreas["ChartAreaName"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
chart.ChartAreas["ChartAreaName"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem,this helpfull for me.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
```